# AsyncTask to post to url returns null exception

Tags: android, post, android-asynctask

I got this code elswhere on stackoverflow.  It did not work for me from the beginning.

To stop initial errors I had to change

```
protected void doInBackground(String... params) {
```

to

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
```

I keep returning an error but e.getmessage returns a null value.

```
public class CallAPI extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

public CallAPI(){
    //set context variables if required
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}


@Override

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String urlString = params[0]; // URL to call

    String data = params[1]; //data to post

    OutputStream out = null;
    Log.i("doinbackground url=", urlString + data);


    try {

        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));

        writer.write(data);

        writer.flush();

        writer.close();

        out.close();

        urlConnection.connect();


    } catch (Exception e) {

        String ErrorMessageJ = "Error message is NULL";
        if (e.getMessage() != null ){ErrorMessageJ = e.getMessage();}
        Log.i("doinbackground e", ErrorMessageJ);




    }
    return null;

}
}
```

Comment: you are returning null and not the url in doInBackground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning `null` in your `doInBackground` check it

may be you need to `Return` some `String` in your `doInBackground` as per params of your `AsyncTask`

Comment: Well I tried returning a string which still isn't helping.  **return "Hello World";**

Comment: Sorry no it did not.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @jim can you share your error with question so i can help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161350/discussion-between-jim-and-nilu).

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer.  The code was mostly fine.  The Null error was because I called the class incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

**An asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params, Progress and Result.**

if in `doInBackground()`accept string then you have to return string value.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String urlString = params[0]; // URL to call
    private String response;;
    String data = params[1]; //data to post
    OutputStream out = null;
    Log.i("doinbackground url=", urlString + data);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        out.close();
        urlConnection.connect();
        response= data[0];

    } catch (Exception e) {
        response=e.getMessage();
        String ErrorMessageJ = "Error message is NULL";
        if (e.getMessage() != null ){ErrorMessageJ = e.getMessage();}
        Log.i("doinbackground e", ErrorMessageJ);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score -1):

Please use Retrofit instead of calling through AsyncTask.
AsyncTask is old and performance is also slow and some drawback like memory leak issue into it.

So i prefer to you used retrofit.

Please check below link it's very useful to you and clear many new concept of core java regarding interface.

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Hope this helps.

Comment: AsyncTask is not slower then Retrofit ... retrofit will also cause memory leak when would be used in the same way ... also Retrofit is not a AsynTask replacement and if he just want to get plain string is not a good choice ... also androidhive is bad refference